# XPath to get an element that does have the "itemtype" attribute

Tags: xpath, microdata

I need to search for microdata in an html page, and I want to search the elements that have the "itemtype" attribute.

The elements could be:
    `<div itemtype="...">`

Or:
    `<strong itemtype="...">`

I do not know which elements I have to search, I just know that they have to have the "itemtype" attribute.
I found something like this:
    `(/bookstore/book[@itemtype='US'])[1]`

But in my case I don't know the name of the element and the value of the attribute.

How can I find out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all the elements that have an `itemtype` attribute, you can use this XPath expression:

```
//*[@itemtype]
```